# ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit: conditional ModalPopup

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I need to show a modal popup if the user has selected a treeview's node on a specific depth.

Is there any way to show a modal popup on a conditional way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the ModalPopupExtender, you can display the modal in a postback. Put the TreeView in an UpdatePanel, and when the node in a specified depth is selected show the modal.